# SQL Date Parameters

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a simple piece of coding I am using in Visual Studio as seen below:-

```
select *
from dbo.NGPTimesheetsPosition
where ProjectNO = @ProjectNO AND CreditorEmployeeID <> 'E0000' AND DocType = 'Time Sheet'
```

That gives me the below results:-

[image]

What I want to do is filter these results by date so that when I use my Date Parameter in Visual studio the results change dependent on date.

What is the best way to code that in?

All help appreciated.

Comment: What have you gotten thus far, code wise?

Comment: i have tried putting in code using GETDATE as below

Comment: select *
from dbo.NGPTimesheetsPosition
where ProjectNO = '12169-01-c' AND CreditorEmployeeID <> 'E0000' AND DocType = 'Time Sheet' AND TransactionDate <GETDATE()